# Unexpected end of JSON input issue only chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest, react-native

I render the HTML page in react native webView using postMessage with following steps:

1. request token
2. on window load add "loginAction" parameter
3. addEventListener and display response
4. convert into an object **(Issue is HERE)**

```
let respAPI = {
"loginToken":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IlFUQXhRa1l5UWpNNVF6RTVRMEU0TkVFM09EaEZRakUxT0RVNVFrRkVOMFF5TWpJeFJqUkRRUSJ9",
};
```

```
window.addEventListener(
  "DOMContentLoaded",
  function () {
    respAPI.loginAction = "loginKey"; // add one parameter
    (window["ReactNativeWebView"] || window).postMessage(
      JSON.stringify(respAPI)
    );
    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false); // window event listener
    function receiveMessage(event) {
      let test = JSON.parse(event.data); // VM5411:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
      console.log(test);
    }
  },
  true
);
```

This SyntaxError error only come in google chrome

Comment: event.data may be an object.JSON.parse won't work in the case of the object.Check for typeof the event.data

Comment: Put some screenshots of error/issue. This code is fine. It is working on chrome.

Comment: Try to look at the actual content of event.data; either do `console.log(event.data)` or add the line `debugger` just before the line where it attempts to parse.